# Showing the person logged in on rails with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a "finish signing up page" in rails.
So the plan is that the admin makes them an account with just an email and a password then sends them a link to log in and change their information. But I can't work out how to print out an update information form.

I'm trying

```
class Users < ApplicationController 
 def update
   @current_nav_identifier = :signup
   @user.current_user = User.current_user
 end
end
```

and I was hoping that the form I have made will print out the update section so the user can update their information.

However this doesn't happen, The `@user.current_user = User.current_user` throws an error so I changed to `@user = User.new` but this doesn't work because I don't want them to have access to add new users, they should only be able to change their information

The idea is that when they sign in for the first time using the generated password they are redirected to this page so they can update their information. This web app is invite only

Any ideas

Comment: What you are required for ?

Comment: Do you know about the authentication gem available in rails named 'Devise' ?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention thta

Comment: Doesn't look like you have gone through the gem docs. It's worth spending sometime on external libraries before you use them.  current_user is a helper method available in controllers and views. And if you want to create a form for the current user, just use form_for current_user and in your controller ensure you have before_action :authenticate_user which will take care of redirecting to whatever path you specify. I'm on phone so couldn't format my comment well. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Go with the gem devise. A very popular gem for authentication in rails application.

```
gem 'devise'
```

[Refer Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: I'm using devise, sorry I forgot to mention that in the main question

Comment: Why you have created the signup controller ? Any specific reason behind the same.

Answer (score 0):

Devise provides a `current_user` method so if you need an `@user` instance variable to create a form for, and you're sure they're logged in, you could use this in the controller:

```
@user = current_user
```

Then you can build a form for them with something like:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```